# tcl split variable after 90 character

Tags: split, tcl

I add together text from variables to file and got to split after 80 character to next line.

```
bind pub "-|-" !maketext pub:textmaker
proc pub:textmaker { nick host handle channel arg } {

    set fid [open text.txt w]
    puts $fid "."
    puts $fid "asdflk asdkflasdfioasd fasdf as dfa sdf a sdf"   
    puts $fid "."
    puts $fid "$arg"    
    puts $fid "."
    puts $fid "."   
    close $fid
}
```

example from text wo i want add

This is one variable: start from "When" to end is "opining".

`!maketext When Conan left NBC, Late night with jimmy Fallon was the only talk show that was left that was kinda Okay. However over the past year Jimmy has matured into a hilarious improviser along with Steve Higgins and their chemistry is amazing. Those two make the opining`

How make after ~80 Characters a new line \n. First After "talk" from example, and next after "matured" and next after "amazing." ....

Comment: There does not seem to be a question here, could you clearly state what the problem is?

Comment: This is one variable: start from "When" to end is "opining".

!maketext When Conan left NBC, Late night with jimmy Fallon was the only talk show that was left that was kinda Okay. However over the past year Jimmy has matured into a hilarious improviser along with Steve Higgins and their chemistry is amazing. Those two make the opining

How make after ~80 Characters a new line \n. First After "talk" from example, and next after "matured" and next after "amazing." ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy with `::textutil::adjust`:

```
% package require textutil

% set s {When Conan left NBC, Late night with jimmy Fallon was the only talk show that was left that was kinda Okay. However over the past year Jimmy has matured into a hilarious improviser along with Steve Higgins and their chemistry is amazing. Those two make the opining}

% ::textutil::adjust $s -length 80 -strictlength true
When Conan left NBC, Late night with jimmy Fallon was the only talk show that
was left that was kinda Okay. However over the past year Jimmy has matured into
a hilarious improviser along with Steve Higgins and their chemistry is amazing.
Those two make the opining
```

If one takes away the `-strictlength` option or set it to `false`, the command will allow single words to go over the limit.

Documentation:
[textutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil.html)